# Why is the compiler showing warning of following if condition to be always true?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{    
int a=2;
 if(a==3,4)
  printf("hello");
return 0;
}
```

Warning: Condition is always true 
Why is it always true??

Comment: This has compiled sir.

Comment: And what value of `a` would cause the number 4 to be false?

Comment: And what is your intention when you write `if(a==3,4)`? If you write strange codes someday compiler may freak out.

Comment: Well i am really upset to hear that. But here's something to say:I tend to prioritize emotional realism above the known laws of time and space, and when you do that, it's inevitable that strange things happen. Which can be quite enjoyable, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `,` doesn't work like you think it does.

What a `,` does is evaluate all the expressions that are separated by the `,` in order, then return the last.

So what your if statement is actually doing is checking `a==3` which returns false, but it discards this result. Then it checks `if(4)`, which returns true.

Essentially your code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{    
    int a=2;
    if(4)
        printf("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

> a==3,4

should be

> a==3.4

Decimal are symbolised with a dot (.) and not a comma(,).
A comma here splits instructions, just as it does in a for statement:

> for(int a=0, int b=10 ; b<=0 ; a++,b--)

Comment: This answer ist just plain wrong.